# CSS variable child-height depending on parent-height

Tags: css, html, height

:)

So the problem is the following:

[image]

The red box is the parent-box.
The blue box will hold Guestbook-comments. 
The yellow box will hold the guestbook-formular.
Now: The green box will hold a line which should be as long as the blue box is. That means that the height of the green box should be equal to the height of the blue box, but not pre-defined.

I tried using "height:100%", but that didnt work out. It gave me a box as big as my screen is.

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Which element defines the height of the group?

Comment: the red one. Also, there is no code yet. Everything I tried is written up there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out [Faux Columns](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/fauxcolumns/), a very common technique used to solve this problem. Essentially, you combine all three backgrounds together into one, and set that image as the background for your containing box. That way, when the containing box grows, so do your inner columns.

Comment: well, this partly solves my problem. I don't want (in my case) to have a 800px (horizontally) big image, of which only 1 pixel has a color. That's a waste of ressources. But thanks :)

Comment: If you're worried about your image's size being too big (which really shouldn't be too big of a concern), just utilize .gif transparency. You can always set the background color of your main element using `background-color`. `.main { background: #fff url(background.gif) 0 0 repeat-y; }`

Comment: didn't know gif supports transparency. Thanks :)